# Change Date Time JSON Return

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON output that displays the date like:

```
"event_start": "2015-12-20 10:00:00",
"event_end": "2015-12-20 12:00:00",
```

When I bring that data in through angular.js, it displays as such but I would like to style it with CSS with having the month, day, and year separate.  Is this even possible?

Comment: It would be nice if you start to accept some answers. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of minor exceptions that don't apply here, CSS can only style elements, not arbitrary bits of text.

Write your JavaScript to split the date up (you'll probably want to add timezone information and run it through `Date()`), and put each segment into a different HTML element.

Then style each element as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using momentjs and then angular's date filter. So somewhere in your controller or service do this.

```
var data.event_start = moment(data.event_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
```

then in html

```
<span ng-bind="vm.data.event_start | 'mediumDate'"></span>
```

and change mediumDate to whatever fits your needs referencing this page.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

```js
  v = "2015-12-20 10:00:00";
  a = v.split(' ');
  b = a[0].split('-');
  str = '<span class="year">' + b[0] + '</span>-' + '<span class="month">' + b[1] + '</span>-' + '<span class="day">' + b[2] + '</span>';
  document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.year{color:red}
.day{color:blue}
```

```html
<div id="t" ></div>
```